# Odds ratio with zero cell counts

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, binomial-distribution, odds-ratio, error-message

I am trying to run a binomial GLM but have some zero cell counts resulting in estimates of +/- infinity. In the text book  "An Introduction to Categorical Data Analysis" Agresti A. (1996) it suggests to add a small constant to the zero cells - which I also came across in the more accessible paper [here](http://www.malariajournal.com/content/11/1/24).

However, when I try this in R I get a warning message of:

> non-integer counts in a binomial glm!.

So:

1. I'm not sure if this is the right thing to do?
2. Is there a better way to deal with zero cell counts?

Data:

```
A<-c(10,10,10,10,10,10,19,19,19,19,19,19)    
B<-c("0","1","2","0","1","2","0","1","2","0","1","2")    
C<-c("-ve","-ve","-ve","+ve","+ve","+ve","-ve","-ve","-ve","+ve","+ve","+ve")    
Dead<-c(1,1,27,0,6,18,2,10,23,0,14,21)    
Alive<-c(29,32,2,22,19,4,28,22,3,20,11,0)
mod2<-glm(cbind(Dead,Alive)~A*B*C, family=binomial)
```

Comment: This doesn't help with the zero cell-count problem but I noticed that you create the object `gaf` but never use it anywhere in the code; the `glm` call only looks at the vectors `Dead` and `Alive` etc, rather than the `data.frame` where you collected them together.

Comment: Thanks - I used it later but forgot to remove it for this question

Answer (score 1):

I think the confusion is stemming from the fact that in a binomial glm formula the *mean* proportion of deaths cannot be zero.  It's ok for some of your observed proportions of deaths to be zero.  The fitting procedure isn't simply taking the log of Dead/Alive, it's finding the maximum likelihood estimates for the following model:
\begin{eqnarray} 
Y_i &\sim& Bin\left( m_i, \mu_i \right), ~~~~\text{for}~~ i=1,...,n, \\
\log\frac{\mu_i}{1-\mu_i} &=& \beta_0 + \beta_1 A_i + \beta_2 B_i + \beta_3 C_i.
\end{eqnarray}
I know your A, B and C covariates are actually factors but the story is the same.  If your observed response $y_i$ is zero, your modelling assumption is that the probability of death $\mu_i$ in this case is probably very low, so that in a random sample of $m_i$ observations you may well see no deaths (which is in fact what you've observed here).

Hope that helps.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand - because it seems to contradict what I have read in the previous references which indicate the observed proportions of deaths cannot be zero. I first notice the problem when I tried to calculate the CIs for the proportions and the CIs for the 0 deaths groups spanned from 0-100%.

Comment: I'm not sure what references you've been looking at.  How about this from Prof. Brian Ripley at Oxford: http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/glm-binomial-with-zero-proportions-td794849.html

Comment: He references the text book 'Modern Applied Statistics with S' 4th edition.

Comment: Do you mean intervals for each $\mu_i$?  How are you calculating them?

Comment: Thanks, I'll try and get hold of it. The references I was referring to are in my original post - including a text book example. Also the following link explains the problem http://rfd.uoregon.edu/files/rfd/StatisticalResources/lgst_zero.txt  - Sorry I don't wan't this to sound rude, it is just difficult to know what to do when there is seemingly conflicting information (it could be me misunderstanding of course)

Comment: I'm using the predict function in R - p<-predict(mod2,newdata=gaf,se.fit=TRUE)
up<-with(p,fit+se.fit)
low<-with(p,fit-se.fit)
invLink<-family(mod2)$linkinv
av2<-with(p,invLink(fit))
upr<-invLink(up)
lwr<-invLink(low)

Comment: The odds ratios calculated at the top of the link refer to observed proportions, so you will get a different answer by fitting a GLM (you are making different modelling assumptions).  I think the problem is more to do with the model you've fitted - some of the confidence intervals for your parameters are enormous, and this can translate to large prediction intervals for your proportions.  If you fit a simpler model instead for example mod3 = glm(cbind(Dead,Alive)~A+B+C, family=binomial), then you get much tighter prediction intervals (including for the 0 death groups).

Comment: Thanks again...but, if I simplify the model the predicted values  differ from the observed - which 1. suggest a bad model (due to zero counts?) and 2. means I can't calculate the CIs for the observed data

Comment: I'm not suggesting you use the exact model I suggested, just that the original model with all the interactions results in many statistically insignificant parameters, therefore very large confidence intervals and therefore you can get large prediction intervals.  If you have zero counts then in a binomial glm there is no way your predicted proportion can be the same as observed (see my answer above).  It's mathematically impossible.  Zero counts may well make your model harder to fit, that is just a consequence of not having a large sample so small prob. death results in no observed deaths.

Comment: You can see that the prediction interval for the case where you have 100% deaths also spans 0-1.  So it's not zero counts, it's cases where the prob. death is either very high or very low, so that in a small sample you may see all deaths or no deaths, which means you have to (to some extent) rely on the other samples to fit your model (since it's hard to know the exact prob. death in these cases - how high is very high?).  I hope that makes things a little clearer.

Comment: OK, both 0% or 100% cause a problem and make it difficult to analyse a full model - which is why it has been suggested by the refs in my original post to add a small constant (presumably take something away from the 100%). But it seems this is not a very recognised thing to do. Thanks again.